# Entity Framework ExecuteSQLCommand returning XML string

Tags: xml, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have the following code:

```
_sql += "SELECT [CodeListNumber] as '@Number'"
_sql += "      ,[ShortDescription]"
_sql += "      ,[ExpiryDate]"
_sql += "      ,[CompositeCode]"
_sql += "  FROM [Aviva_Guidewire_Dev_V3].[dbo].[Aviva_CompleteCodeList] as [CodeListNumber]"
_sql += "  order by [CodeListNumber]"
_sql += "  for xml path('CodeList'), root('CodeLists'), elements"

Dim params As String()
Dim _Rtn As String = _dbRoot.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(_sql, params)
Dim _xDoc As New XmlDocument
_xDoc.LoadXml(_Rtn)
```

If I run the above SQL statement directly in SSMS, it returns a value called XML_[some guid].

When I run the code within VS 2012, the value _Rtn is -1 and that is all I get. I can see that ExecuteSQLCommand can have a parms array, but am not sure what I should be doing in this case.

Should I change the code to be a stored proc and just call it?

Or can someone show me how to create the same code using Linq to Entities, or Linq to SQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By specifying [FOR XML](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) clause in the query you are retrieving the results of a SQL query as a Sql Server [XML datatype](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx), not a string

[Database.ExecuteSqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) executes commands used for creating or modifying database structures or inserting, deleting and updating data. i.e. not querying.

For queries you need [Database.SqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). It will return elements of a given type but xml isn't a primitive type so it won't work with the query as it stands. If you need xml either serialise the xml returned by the query in sql server to a string, or remove the FOR XML clause and create a type with properties that match the names of the columns returned from the query. Then serialise the instance created in the C# code to xml.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for anyone else that is interested.

Moved the SQL directly into a Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CompleteListofCodes]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    -- <@Param1, sysname, @p1> <Datatype_For_Param1, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param1, , 0>, 
    -- <@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT [CodeListNumber] as '@Number'
      ,[ShortDescription]
      ,[ExpiryDate]
      ,[CompositeCode]
  FROM [DB_V3].[dbo].[CompleteCodeList] as [CodeListNumber]
  order by [CodeListNumber]
  for xml path('CodeList'), root('CodeLists'), elements

END
```

Then I just call the stored procedure after adding the function in the EF model.

```
Dim _Rtn As String() = _dbRoot.CompleteListofCodes().Array
Dim _BuildXML as string =Nothing
For Each _Element as string in _Rtn
    _BuildXML += _Element.ToString()
Next
Dim _xDoc As New XmlDocument
_xDoc.LoadXml(_BuildXML)
```

As there appears to be a 2K limit on the array strings returned, I just concatenate them to produce the final string to use in the LoadXML statement.

Simples!